# Zend Imap, fetching emails in Gmail Labels

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, gmail-imap, zend-gdata

I am using [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.read.html) to fetch email messages from Gmail, Currently I am only able to get messages in INBOX only, 
After Authentication i setToken and other parameters

```
 $imap->requestAndResponse('AUTHENTICATE', $authenticateParams);

 $response = $imap->requestAndResponse('XLIST', $imap->escapeString('', '*'));
```

in the $responce Variable i am getting list of all my Labels/folders

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => XLIST
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => \HasNoChildren
                )

            [2] => /
            [3] => Calendar
        ).................... INBOX, Sent Mails Etc
```

and so on, After doing some code and fetching Names on Index [3] Which are my Labels and Folders.

i Have list in array like below.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Calendar
    [1] => Drafts
    [2] => Facebook Mails
    [3] => Inbox
    [4] => Junk E-mail
    [5] => Logs
    [6] => Personal Mails
    [7] => Sent Items
    [8] => Office Mails
)
```

Now i want to fetch emails in each message/folders

I tried **`Zend_Mail_Storage_Folder_Maildir`** but i do not Know exactly how to fetch  messages in each of the above folder, I am using Imap,

By Opening Storage like below

**`$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($imap);`**

This only returns mails in Inbox Folder.

Comment: Think there is no way to do this. I have solved it by fetching the Messages from "All Mails" Folder.

Answer (score 2):

To Display All folders

```
    $storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($this->imap);
    $folders = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($storage->getFolders(), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    echo '<select name="folder">';
    foreach ($folders as $localName => $folder) {
        $localName = str_pad('', $folders->getDepth(), '-', STR_PAD_LEFT) .
                $localName;
        echo '<option';
        if (!$folder->isSelectable()) {
            echo ' disabled="disabled"';
        }
        echo ' value="' . htmlspecialchars($folder) . '">'
        . htmlspecialchars($localName) . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

To Select a Folder

```
$storage->selectFolder("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
```

**[Gmail]/Sent Mail** label for select sent mail folder